# DocumentDB how to reduce RU's for request

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In my collection I am writing a query and get the top 500 records, In that when I specified partition key it consuming high RU's and if I not specify a partition key I will show `REQUEST CHARGE 0 RU's` are used.

What are the steps needed to follow minimize the RU's. For each request when query filters large amount of data with multiple conditions and getting a large amount of data.

Comment: Looks like a too broad question to me. Code example would help.

Comment: OK. thank you for replay Mikhail

Comment: Without seeing your query (and resulting RU), there's really no way to help. Also, not sure what you consider "high RU's". Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: More info about RU, please refer to the [Request Units in DocumentDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-request-units)